# Force cache refresh after deployment

Tags: php, .htaccess, uri, cache-control

Is there a way to force a client's cache to reload an HTML file if you can't change the URI referencing that file (e.g., can't add a timestamp param)?

Here's my situation:

- A plugin deployed to a 1000 users
- That plugin loads `example.com/page.html` which calls on `script.js`
- The resource URI `example.com/page.html` cannot be changed (w/o plugin updates)
- `page.html` has been changed. I need to clear the old `page.html` from users' cache so the new `page.html` can load.

Any ideas? Htaccess? The PHP API that the old & new `page.html` call on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, if the page is already cached by a browser it's difficult to tell it not to use its cached version because it probably won't bother to check again before it determines its cached version is stale. You'll just have to send a snail-mail letter to all of your users informing them to press ctrl+f5 :)

There is a chance that the browser might at least try a HEAD request to check the modified timestamp before it serves up its cached version, though. In this case the following will help you out.

Browsers negotiate their content from your web server using HTTP standard headers. Going forward if you want to tell a browser not to cache a file, you have to send the appropriate HTTP headers. If you want to do this in PHP you can use the `header` function to send the appropriate HTTP headers to the browser:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

If it has to be done via HTML you can do the following in your page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1995 12:12:12 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

There is no way for you to be sure if the browser will honor your request that it not cache a page, however. There are some other things like eTags and whatnot but frankly I don't think that's going to help you out if the page is already cached.

---

**UPDATE**

From the HTTP/1.1 specification on [Response Cacheability](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4):

> If there is neither a cache validator nor an explicit expiration time
>   associated with a response, we do not expect it to be cached, but
>   certain caches MAY violate this expectation (for example, when little
>   or no network connectivity is available).

Comment: not sure if this accomplishes my goal. The PHP file I have control over is an API called on by a js file from `example.html`. The `header` solution you provided seems like it'd only work for the php file itself? Or would it work for all resources on the same domain? As for the HTML solution, that works if the old `example.html` file already included those tags, but as described above, that's not the case for my situation.

Comment: Otherwise said, I'm trying to load a new `example.html` over an old `example.html` that's already cached.

Comment: Sadly, once the browser has cached something, there's not a lot you can do about it. The good thing is most browsers don't cache stuff for a long time. Just the facts of life, I'm afraid.

Comment: The PHP API may have been wishful thinking, but you'd think that you could force the refresh at the Apache level. Anyway, that's a relief that HTML's not cached for long. I'll leave it alone and accept your answer if no one has any miracle solutions.

Comment: Yeah I can't imagine a browser caching anything longer than a day (at most) without at least checking the server to see if the file has been modified. I *think* it's usually more along the lines of an hour or two, though, unless they're explicitly told to cache it longer by your server.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps PHP could be used to add a timestamp to the javascript call.  You could then run this for the duration...........For example:

> check_if_cache_should_be_disabled.php
>
> ```
> <?php
> $deployment_flag = true; // Uncomment this if you want to disable normal cache.
> //$deployment_flag = false // Uncomment this if you want to enable normal cache.
> ?>
> ```

---

> page.php
>
> ```
> <script src="/js/script.js<?php 
> require('check_if_cache_should_be_disabled.php');
> //  File Get Contents can be used for a remote server
> //file_get_contents('http://yourserver.com/check_if_cache_should_be_disabled.php');
> if ($deployment_flag == true) {
> print ( '?ts='.date() );
> }
> ?>"></script>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be oversimplified, but you could always append a GET value to the end of the file that contains a file version. Modern browsers usually take that as a new version and will ignore previous caches and fetch the newest one. So all you'd have to do is update the version when you want the most up-to-date code to be cached instead.

For example:

```
<script type="javascript" src="example.js?version=2.0.8"></script>
```

You could even go as far as writing a PHP script that automatically does this for you when a file changes based on some specific parameter like "last updated."

Comment: I do this but using the git hash - that way, every time I push a change via git, the caches get invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file name, for example page_v2.html which will make the browser load the page as a new page.

Comment: I found that even this doesn't help with Chrome.  It will happily continue to load files that don't even exist.

Comment: @nuander Indeed that is true. Firefox can even be stubborn at times for resources such as css and js using ?<timestamp> also, but Chrome seems to be worse.  It can be hair-pulling at times as the behavior seems inconsistent.

Comment: I have seen web pages which use .php files to serve up css and js resources.  I am guessing that is so headers can be sent to force reload, eg Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=0