# How to identify bugs that don't repeat on your devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

I have a bug that I can't reproduce on my computer, but I keep getting bug reports with screenshots (see attached).

The bug is with the parallax image positioning on this website http://nuccobrain.com/staging/change.php, where the image is positioned too high or too low (revealing the black background behind it).

Can someone advise me on how I can reproduce and pinpoint this bug, and/or debug it?

- Could it be because these users need to clear their cache from when I last fixed this bug? How can I force all users to clear their cache automagically?
- I understood how paroller.js (parallax script) positions these images, but couldn't see why that code would go wrong, unless the page height and/or scroll position was calculated incorrectly.

Thanks in advance for providing a protocol for pinning down bug reports with website rendering.

[image]

Comment: Do the bug reports describe the steps to reproduce the bug?

Comment: From your HTTP response headers it seems that caching may be a problem. For CSS it's enough to add `style.css?ver=2` to make sure it's refreshed, but for the main html, generated by PHP, you can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937447/force-cache-refresh-after-deployment but the HTML version should not work, you would need to add `header` lines to PHP script.

Comment: It may not work as expected, since my browser doesn't try to even check the headers, it may take another month for all browsers to update, but from that time it should be refreshing properly. You can also enable Etag on the http server, and add that `header` in PHP on all pages. For the moment, clients can refresh page with F5 or CTRL-F5 to see the latest version. In your HTTP headers, it says that the page should be cached for month. This is not optimal for many reasons, it should have etag enabled instead.

Comment: You should remove header from PHP page `Expires: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 16:51:47 GMT`, this way, page web browsers should download PHP every time they visit a website which is most optimal.