# In PHP, Web page load every time from browser cache

Tags: php

I added code into my website pages for browser cache control on live server. But I didn't get any response from my browser. Every time load my page from the browser cache.

Please, Anybody, help me?

```
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=30000');

$file_last_mod_time = filemtime(__FILE__);

$content_last_mod_time = 1520949851;

$etag = '"' . $file_last_mod_time . '.' . $content_last_mod_time . '"';

header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');

header('ETag: ' . $etag);

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] == $etag) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified', true, 304);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: How can i prevent browser cache?

Comment: browser cache is client-side. not server side

Comment: Right, Can we control browser cache on server server using above code?

Comment: Because i am facing cache problem every time while i make to change any thing on website. it's not appear without head refresh.

Comment: @AmitShakya can you share some HTML and/or Javascript of how you are loading that content?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Comment: https://brahmagems.com/ it's my website link.

Comment: I have found few solutions but can't be worked.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-caching-headers/

Comment: @AmitShakya I assume you already found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937447/force-cache-refresh-after-deployment

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me and I solved it by using this method.
**Create a file called clear.php, Paste the following code and Run.**

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
?>
```