# How to clear cache in chrome when release new Vue app version

Tags: firebase, vue.js, caching, vuejs2, firebase-hosting

Created an app in vue-cli and then I build the dist folder for production with a new app version.
The problem occurs when I have to make some changes and I have to redo the deployment. After this,App doesn't work with updated version but if I clear the chrome cache in the site settings of the particular site , the app works fine again.
The app is deployed on Firebase Hosting.
A solution to  clear chrome cache when I release a new vue version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force cache refresh after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937447/force-cache-refresh-after-deployment)

Comment: I've updated your tags to include `firebase`, since this is a hosting/server-side issue and you may get better answers there.

Answer (score 1):

The "smart" caching can be done by the server-side technology. If you have access to this and can manage the type of caching, you can set it to use `etag`, which I've found is quite reliable.

Vue apps, bundled using webpack, will generate filenames with hashes. So if there is anything different in the app, or chunk(if you're code splitting) the generated file names will be different. The issue though is that the `index.html` will keep the same name. So if you can set the correct caching options for that file alone, that will solve most of your problems. Alternatively, you can set a really short cache time or no cache at all (since it should be a small file) if you're concerned about the page loading from cache. But the problem still remains that this part of the caching functionality is entirely out of reach of the vue app.

Looks like with firebase you can edit the configuration and set headers per resource [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config)

so you could set a long `max-age` for css and js, and short for `index.html` like so...

```json
    "headers": [ {
      "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      } ]
    }, {
      "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=7200"
      } ]
    }, {
      "source": "index.html",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=300"
      } ]
    } ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating my project.solution :the version number in package.json before running the build command fixed it.
package.json file:

```
{
   "name": "project-name",
   "version": "0.1.1",
   "private": true,
    ...
}
```